# finite order element in free product

Tags: group-theory

Show that the free product $G * H$ of nontrivial groups $G$ and $H$ has trivial center,
and that the only elements of $G * H$ of finite order are the conjugates of finite-order
elements of $G$ and $H$

I can prove first part but how we can prove only elements of $G * H$ of finite order are the conjugates of finite-order
elements of $G$ and $H$?

Comment: Every element not in a conjugate of $G$ or of $H$ is conjugate to an element of form $g_1h_1 \cdots g_kh_k$ or $h_1g_1 \cdots h_kg_k$ for some $k \ge 1$, where $g_i \in G \setminus\{1\}$, $h_i \in H \setminus \{1\}$, and such elements clearly have infinite order.

Comment: @DerekHolt Just out of curiosity. Instead of having two groups in the family, we have a family of groups say $\{G_i\}_{i \in I}$. What does an element looks like in the product group that is not conjugate of an element in $U_{i \in I} G_i$. I had a hard timing with writing down notation that works for general cases.

Answer (score 2):

The free product of two groups $G*H$ acts on a simplicial tree $T$ by isometries (the Bass-Serre tree) without inverting edges, the stabilizer of a vertex  of $T$ is conjugate to $G$ or $H$. Finally an isometry  $g$ of $T$ that does nor reverse edges and is  of finite order must fix a vertex.